# std::async works only synchronously

Tags: c++, asynchronous, lambda, future

im trying to add a async method to my A Star Class. I want to be able to calculate the Path asynchronously, so every agent is able to find his path independent from the other agents.

The problem is, at the moment it seems like that the programm is waiting until the thread has finished. 
How can i execute every call asynchronously?

Function

```
bool simplePath::navAgent::findPathAsync(int _startX, int _startY, int _endX, int _endY){
    auto t1 = std::async([&]{return this->findPath(_startX,_startY,_endX,_endY);});
    t1.get();
    return true;
}
```

Call

```
navComponent->findPathAsync(0,2,30,45);
    navComponent->findPathAsync(0,2,123,100);
    navComponent->findPathAsync(0,2,8,7);
    navComponent->findPathAsync(0,2,8,7);
    navComponent->findPathAsync(0,2,8,7);
    navComponent->findPathAsync(0,2,8,7);
    navComponent->findPathAsync(0,2,8,7);
```

What is my mistake here?

Comment: [`t1.get()` will have to wait for the result](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/get), so what do you expect to happen? (Also important when writing multithreaded code: how are you compiling?)

Comment: You will need to store `t1` futures in some container (paying memory overhead) and then call `.get()` on each stored item. Also it seems that you actually want to perform those calculations in parallel, rather than asynchronously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `t1.get()` your code is waiting for the result to be calculated.

When you launch your tasks you aren't specifying a launch policy so you are using the default policy of `std::launch::async | std::launch::deferred` which may not launch a separate thread at all and could just be lazily evaluated when you call `t1.get()`.

You need to change your lambda to capture by value rather than by reference as the integer parameters you are referencing may no longer exist when your lambda is executed.

A fully working example would be:

```
std::future<bool> simplePath::navAgent::findPathAsync(int _startX, int _startY, int _endX, int _endY){
    return std::async(std::launch::async, []{return this->findPath(_startX,_startY,_endX,_endY);});
}

std::vector< std::future_bool > results;
results.emplace_back(navComponent->findPathAsync(0,2,30,45));
results.emplace_back(navComponent->findPathAsync(0,2,123,100));
results.emplace_back(navComponent->findPathAsync(0,2,8,7));
results.emplace_back(navComponent->findPathAsync(0,2,8,7));
results.emplace_back(navComponent->findPathAsync(0,2,8,7));
results.emplace_back(navComponent->findPathAsync(0,2,8,7));
results.emplace_back(navComponent->findPathAsync(0,2,8,7));

bool result = true;
for ( auto& f : results )
{
    result &= f.get();
}
```